# Javascript pdf font embed Unicode to non Unicode conversion based on font file

Tags: javascript, unicode, pdf-generation, truetype, pdfmake

I'm using [pdfmake](http://pdfmake.org/#/) plugin to generate pdf. I embedded Marathi (One of the Indian languages) font in the pdf it's working fine but the problem is I can't use Unicode characters because every font file (.ttf) has own set of conversion to convert Unicode characters to non-Unicode characters which are maintained inside true type font file.

1. I'm using **Lakhani.ttf** font file to display Marathi text
2. Whenever I want to display Marathi text then I need to convert
       Unicode characters to Lakhani encoding characters using this website :
       http://service.vishalon.net/pramukh-font-converter/marathi

   e.g I want to convert this **मराठी** Unicode text than I have to go above conversion website I need to choose font as **Marathi Lekhani** and I need to type the Unicode character in the right side input field then I have to press  <--- button then I'll get output as **mra#I**. so, if I'm using this text **mra#I** along with Lakhani font then it will display the exact text what I want.

Problem is I want to display dynamic Marathi text inside the pdf I don't know how above website doing this conversion. I want to know the conversion logic or Is there any alternative way to display the Marathi Unicode characters inside the pdf with .ttf file?

I will appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution. If I'm using Google Noto (https://www.google.com/get/noto/#serif-deva) font file instead of Lekhani.ttf then there is no need extra conversion we can use directly Unicode characters.